# Google Bigquery: add IP CIDR range to service account

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a service account for reading and writing to a bigquery table. Is it possible to implement IP CIDR range to service account? Basically white list IP from which service account can access the table?

Or in other words, what is the best way to restrict access to service account based on IP!

Comment: adding VPC service controls for Bq should work https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/create-service-perimeters#create-perimeter

Comment: I had followed this, but my service account was still able to access bigquery outside the IP specified in VPC service controls. What could be wrong?

Comment: check if the allowed ip's is in between the allowed ip cidr ranges and also perhaps with access context manager. https://cloud.google.com/access-context-manager/docs/overview#:~:text=Access%20Context%20Manager%20allows%20Google,and%20resources%20in%20Google%20Cloud.      it is a little difficult to provide solution where it has multi step configurations hence why recommending links to google doco.